# Printing formatted rtf in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, rtf

I got help from Mark Hall on printing text on top of picture in VB.Net; the sub I am using for printing is as below:

```
  Private Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  _
  System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim rect1 As Rectangle = New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), PictureBox1.Image.Size)
    Dim rect2 As Rectangle = New Rectangle(New Point(100, 200), PictureBox1.Image.Size)
    Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat()
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(PictureBox1.Image, rect1)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(rtfMekdam, RichTextBox1.Font, New SolidBrush(Color.Red), rect2, fmt)
End Sub
```

Obviously the last line of the code limit formatting of the text;
Now I have created a formatted RichTextBox (below) and want to print it as shown; I could not modify the last line of the Sub to do this; any help appreciated.
[image]

How to print the formatted rtf shown in the image above; as currently shown in my RichTextBox –

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to print the formatted rtf shown in the image above; ir is currently shown in my RichTextBox

Comment: See [How to print the content of a RichTextBox control by using Visual Basic .NET](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/811401)

Comment: Thanks for the link; I will read it and post my comments later on.